# Chamada de sistema em c/c++

Tags: c

Ola eu preciso fazer uma chamada de sistema(em c/c++) que liste o consumo de memoria dos processos alguem tem alguma ideia de como eu posso fazer isso ? eu estou usando o linux como s.o

Comment: teria que ler os ficheiros na pasta /proc

Answer (score 2):

Você pode listar todos os processos usando comando **ps -eo pid, comm** (Retorna o PID e o nome do processo) e consultar as informações de memória de cada um deles usando **/proc/$PID/statm** (Retorna a memória total do processo pelo número de páginas) ou **/proc/$PID/status** no campo VmSize (Memória em Kb). Para ler as informações, basta usar as funções de leitura de arquivo para coletar os dados do seu interesse.

As informações do comando ps estão aqui: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html

Todas as informações dos dados retornados pelos comandos relacionados ao proc aqui: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: eu to vendo aqui por exemplo o comando top faz algo parecido ou estou enganado ? mas me parece que o ps(trabalha com processos) é o que eu estou procurando mesmo.Tenho também que matar um processo atraves de uma implementaçao de um programa que usa a chamada para matar os processos que estejam consumindo mais memória que o valor passado como parâmetro.Alguma ideia?